# web application using asp.net management

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am writing a web application using asp.net management. I have changed the Application Name at the beginning of my program to 'Web'

I then add a user and password into the management database, it adds the user twice once with the 'Web' applicationID and also with '/' applicationID

if I then change my Application Name inside the program to 'Test' and create another new user the user is also added twice with 'Test' and '/' as the applicationID

I do not want users entered with the '/' applicationid. Can I stop this?

Comment: what's asp.net management?

Comment: asp.net management is the aspnet_regsql database password security